# How I can display another (change) ViewController when I select a picker

Tags: swift, button, viewcontroller, picker

How I can display another (change) ViewController when I select a picker.

I have a picker (easy, intermediate, hard) and when I select a picker and I click a buton I would like to go to specific view controller ( I have 3 view controller ( one for the easy, one for the intermediate and the other for the hard)
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you can either present or push view controller. If you have connected it with segue you can do something like:

```
if(easySelected)
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"easyOne" sender:self];
else if
   ...
```

If you have navigation controller or want to present it you can do:

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
EasyViewConroller *cont = [story instantiateInitialViewController];
// or EasyViewConroller *cont = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourIdent"];
// in former solution you have to set that identifier in the code/storyboard 

// navigation/push
self.navigationController pushViewController:cont animated:YES];

// if you want to present it
[self presentViewController:cont animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Edit:

```
if(easySelected){
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("easyOne" sender:self)
{
else if{
   ...
}

//If you have navigation controller or want to present it you can do:
var tempStory = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
var tempVC = tempStory.instantiateInitialViewController() as! EasyViewController

//present
self.presentViewController(tempVC, animated: true)

//push
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tempVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Sure, give me 10 minutes

Comment: Sorry I didn't undersatnd if you gave it to me two possibility or what?

Comment: three options: segue, present and push to navigation controller